# IntelliJ, Java Path, Create Read Write File

Tags: java, intellij-idea

i have a short question and after hours of trying around I still don't get a solution.

I have a resource directory in the project directory and I want to acess to it, because I want to write something into it.
With this it is working under Windows 8.1 Pro, but for some reason it is not working under Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS, I am using on both IntelliJ

```
Path map = Paths.get("group34/resource/MapData/"+name);

try { Files.createFile(map); }
    catch (FileAlreadyExistsException x) {  System.err.format("file named %s already exists%n", map); }
    catch (IOException x) {                 System.err.format("createFile error: %s%n", x); }    // Some other sort of failure, such as permissions.
```

I am getting this:

```
IOException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: teame4/resource/MapData/null.map
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: teame4/resource/MapData/null.map
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2784)
    at de.hhu.propra.CreateSafeMap.loadMap(CreateSafeMap.java:101)
    at de.hhu.propra.CreateSafeMap.main(CreateSafeMap.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at de.hhu.propra.CreateSafeMap.loadMap(CreateSafeMap.java:117)
    at de.hhu.propra.CreateSafeMap.main(CreateSafeMap.java:129)
```

Hope you can help me getting it working.

Comment: Are you sure you have write protection to the contents of that folder? you can check with `ls -l` to see the user and group the folder belongs to. If it is root or any other user or group your user acount is not apart of then that could be the issue.

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 5 sparkay sparkay  4096 Mai  8 10:26

Comment: Have you created parent directories (teame4/resource/MapData/) before trying to create the file?

Comment: It seems that the code in the post is not causing the exception (or I'm missing something). Can you indicate CreateSafeMap line 101 ?

Comment: yes they are existing | drwxrwxr-x 2 sparkay sparkay 4096 Mai  8 13:15 MapData<br/> `try(BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(map, charset))
        {
            lineBackup=reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Total characters in the string/document: " +lineBackup.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }`

Comment: Look like you are running with the wrong working directoty in the run configuration.

Comment: Can you tell me how wrong? As I said it works fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried iton Ubuntu 14 and it works for me given the following directory stucture:

```
project root
|
+-src
| |
| +-main
|  |
|  +-java
|   |
|   +-Main.java
|
+-group34
  |
  +-resource
    |
    +-MapData
```

What is your directory stucture?

Comment: `Project (the root)
    |
    teame4
    |
    +-src
    |  |
    |  |
    |  +-de.hhu.propra
    |        |
    |        my Java Classes
    |     
   +-rescource
         |
        MapData`

Comment: If you add this :
System.out.println(map.toAbsolutePath().toString()); 
then does it print the full path you would expect?

Comment: In your folder stucture there is no group34. It is hard to interpret your folder stucture because it is in one line, could you add it to the question?

Comment: Thank you!!!
I had to use this! Going to tidy the entire code up. And sorry for the... bad directory structure... With group34, this was / is my mistake , I forgot i am actually in another project :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your compilation and build steps are working correctly, as your code says your looking for `'group34/...'` but your exception indicates the request was for '`teame4/...'`.

This suggests to me that you're possibly not building correctly and are running 'old' class-files?

Comment: Huh, didnt noticed the tipo... Was thinking of another project sorry, my fault